# Haskell coprime negative integers?

Tags: haskell

```
coprime a b = gcd a b == 1
```

This should theoretically compute whether two integers are coprime but I am wondering what exactly happens in the Haskell 'compiler' if I were to run, say, `coprime -3 4`. If this were `coprime 3 4` the program would run fine and return `True`. How does the Haskell compiler deal with negative numbers in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the Haskell compiler that calculates this. It is the [`gcd` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:gcd) from the standard library. The [source code of the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#gcd):

```
gcd             :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
{-# NOINLINE [1] gcd #-}
gcd x y         =  gcd' (abs x) (abs y)
                   where gcd' a 0  =  a
                         gcd' a b  =  gcd' b (a `rem` b)
```

shows that it first takes the absolute value of the two arguments before calculating the greatest common denominator.